# how to sort mixed numeric/alphanumeric array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sorting

I have a mixed array that I need to sort by number, alphabet and then by digit-

```
['A1', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'A3A', 'A3B', 'A3', 'A4', 'B10', 'B2', 'F1', '1', '2', 'F3']
```

how do I sort it to be like:

```
['1', '2', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A3A', 'A3B', 'A4', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'B2', 'B10', 'F1', 'F3']
```

Here is what I tried:

```
var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
var reN = /[^0-9]/g;
function sortAlphaNum(a, b) {
    var AInt = parseInt(a.Field, 10);
    var BInt = parseInt(b.Field, 10);

    if (isNaN(AInt) && isNaN(BInt)) {
        var aA = (a.Field).replace(reA, "");
        var bA = (b.Field).replace(reA, "");
        if (aA === bA) {
            var aN = parseInt((a.Field).replace(reN, ""), 10);
            var bN = parseInt((b.Field).replace(reN, ""), 10);
            return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
        }
    } else if (isNaN(AInt)) {//A is not an Int
        return 1;//to make alphanumeric sort first return -1 here
    } else if (isNaN(BInt)) {//B is not an Int
        return -1;//to make alphanumeric sort first return 1 here
    } else {
        return AInt > BInt ? 1 : -1;
    }
}

fieldselecteddata.sort(sortAlphaNum);
```

but that only sorts it alphabetically/numeric till combination of 1 numeric and 1 character like `A1`, `A2`, `A10`. But if there will be values like `A3A`, `A3B` in that case it wont sort properly. Can this be done with either straight JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: @RameshRajendran That's **not** a valid excuse for an off-topic question, this is indeed on-topic and a good question. It doesn't matter if this is a homework question or not. The user put forth a clear goal and output, along with that an attempted solution. That's much better then most the questions I see here.

Comment: @RameshRajendran This is actually a very good question. It should be protected instead of closed.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var arr = ['A1', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'A3A', 'A3B', 'A3', 'A4', 'B10', 'B2', 'F1', '1', '2', 'F3'];

// regular expression to get the alphabetic and the number parts, if any
var regex = /^([a-z]*)(\d*)/i;

function sortFn(a, b) {
  var _a = a.match(regex);
  var _b = b.match(regex);

  // if the alphabetic part of a is less than that of b => -1
  if (_a[1] < _b[1]) return -1;
  // if the alphabetic part of a is greater than that of b => 1
  if (_a[1] > _b[1]) return 1;

  // if the alphabetic parts are equal, check the number parts
  var _n = parseInt(_a[2]) - parseInt(_b[2]);
  if(_n == 0) // if the number parts are equal start a recursive test on the rest
      return sortFn(a.substr(_a[0].length), b.substr(_b[0].length));
  // else, just sort using the numbers parts
  return _n;
}

console.log(arr.sort(sortFn));
```

**Note:** the `i` modifier in the regular expression (`/.../i`) means *case-insensitive* (looks for both lowercases and uppercases).

Comment: The output mismatch with what is OP exceptation ` "A1",
  "A3A",
  "A3B",
  "A3",
`

Comment: @RameshRajendran I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this functionality. it give the result which you want exactly

```js
   var arr = ['A1', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'A3A', 'A3B', 'A3', 'A4', 'B10', 'B2', 'F1', '1', '2', 'F3'];
function sortFn(a, b) {     
    var ax = [], bx = [];
    a.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { ax.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });
    b.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { bx.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });        
    while(ax.length && bx.length) {
        var an = ax.shift();
        var bn = bx.shift();
        var nn = (an[0] - bn[0]) || an[1].localeCompare(bn[1]);
        if(nn) return nn;
    }
    return ax.length - bx.length;      
}
console.log(arr.sort(sortFn));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort it with splitted array by type and check for equality first and then by type.

```js
var array = ['A1', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'A3A', 'A3B', 'A3', 'A4', 'B10', 'B2', 'F1', '1', '2', 'F3'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var isNumber = function (v) { return (+v).toString() === v; },
        aa = a.match(/\d+|\D+/g),
        bb = b.match(/\d+|\D+/g),
        i = 0,
        l = Math.min(aa.length, bb.length);

    while (i < l && aa[i] === bb[i]) {
        i++;
    }
    if (i === l) {
        return aa.length - bb.length;
    }
    if (isNumber(aa[i]) && isNumber(bb[i])) {
        return aa[i] - bb[i];
    }
    return aa[i].localeCompare(bb[i]);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var a=[ {
    "LIST": "14:NATURAL RESOURCES"
},
{
    "LIST": "7:DIVERSITY IN LIVING ORGANISMS"
},
{
    "LIST": "3:ATOMS AND MOLECULES"
},
{
    "LIST": "10:GRAVITATION"
},
{
    "LIST": "6:TISSUES"
}]

var c=a.sort(function(a,b){
let aa=a.LIST,bb=b.LIST;
return parseInt(aa.split(":")[0] - bb.split(":")[0])

})

console.log(c)
```