# Array sort with mixed alphabetical and numerical content not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a JavaScript Array called `years` with some dates and one textual item like so: `[ "2017", "2018", "2019", "historic" ]`

I want to sort it so that 'historic' comes first, and then the remaining numbers are sorted numerically.

The following sort function works perfectly in every browser I have tested apart from Firefox, which leaves 'historic' at the end of the array:

```
years.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a === 'historic') {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return a - b;
    }
});
```

I tried adding the following console log:

```js
let years = [ "2017", "2018", "2019", "historic" ];
years.sort((a, b) => {
    console.log(a);
    if (a === 'historic') {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return a - b;
    }
});
```

Firefox outputs the following:

```
2017 index.js:409
2018 index.js:409
2019
```

Suggesting it never processes the 'historic' array element.

Comment: The elements `a` and `b` might get passed into the comparison function in any order - you only checked if `a` was `historic`, but you neglected to handle the case when `b` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a symetrically check for both elements and check if a value is `'historic'`. Then return the delta of the check or the delta of the values.

```js
var array = ["2017", "2018", "2019", "historic"];

array.sort((a, b) => (b === 'historic') - (a === 'historic') || a - b);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `sort()` could be called with "historic" passed as argument `b`, not `a`.

Looks like you should use more complex comparator. Check this question - [how to sort mixed numeric/alphanumeric array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972652/how-to-sort-mixed-numeric-alphanumeric-array-in-javascript)